# raphael js drawing arcs starting at 6 o'clock that cocentric

Tags: raphael

I was able to find an example of a Polar clock at http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html

I modified it to draw concentric circles, but I need the arc to start at 6 o'clock. I am trying to dissect how it works, but haven't been able to figure it out.

JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5frQ8/

```
var r = Raphael("holder", 600, 600);

// Custom Attribute
r.customAttributes.arc = function (value, total, R, color) 
{
    var alpha = 360 / total * value,
        a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
        x = 300 + R * Math.cos(a),
        y = 300 - R * Math.sin(a),
        path;
    if (total == value) 
    {
        path = [["M", 300, 300 - R], ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, 299.99, 300 - R]];
    } 
    else 
    {
        path = [["M", 300, 300 - R], ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]];
    }
    return {path: path, stroke: color,"stroke-width": 30};
};

//West
r.path().attr({arc: [575, 2000, 200, '#19A69C']});

//Total#
r.path().attr({arc: [1000, 2000, 160, '#FEDC38']});

//East
r.path().attr({arc: [425, 2000, 120, '#7BBD26']});
```

Answer (score 3):

I have modified the main function to make the arcs start from 6 o'clock equivalent position. Please note that the formulae to find a point in polar coordinates are always:

```
x = centerX + radius * cos(angle)
y = centerY + radius * sin(angle)
```

Find the starting and ending points accordingly.

To change the starting angle by "delta", all angles should be added by "delta". Thus,

```
newAngle = angle + delta
```

The values of delta are -90 and +90 for the arcs to start from 12 o'clock and 6 o'clock respectively.

The arc drawing function is changed accordingly.

```
// Custom Attribute
r.customAttributes.arc = function (value, total, R, color) 
{
    var angleShift = 90,
        alpha = 360 / total * value,
        a = (alpha + angleShift) * Math.PI / 180,
        x = 300 + R * Math.cos(a),
        y = 300 + R * Math.sin(a),
        path;
    if (total == value) 
    {
        path = [["M", 300, 300 + R], ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, 300.01, 300 + R]];
    } 
    else 
    {
        path = [["M", 300, 300 + R], ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]];
    }
    return {path: path, stroke: color,"stroke-width": 30};
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great!! Do you have a reference on how the formulas work? Also is there a way I can shift the graph to start at the top right of my canvas?

Comment: I figured out my other question! Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisMuench, You may check the following link to study the relation between polar and cartesian coordinates. http://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html